# Get Inner Html of aspx page in Asp.Net web project for email

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

Using `ASP.NET`...

I have an email button on a `popup extender` and would like to use the inner `html` of another `aspx` page to use for the body, then edit a couple tags before it is sent. Is this possible?

Basically I'm using the `.Net.Mail.MailMessage` to create an `HtmlBody` and want to grab the `html` of another page (without actually rendering the page) as opposed to recreating it in a string.

Comment: This is just a bit vague. Can you expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all creating html emails doesn't allow for complicated html (internal,external styling, and other controls) see...

[Html Email Guidline](http://css-tricks.com/133-using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/).

So what I did was use the following to create an html string for emailing...

1) Create a simple .htm file as a template, formatting everything in standard html tables (not asp:tables), and other standard html tags.

2) Only use in-line styling if necessary.

3) Then create replacable text words or phrases to replace. You can also use a comment to replace text or for adding to a table see markup below

```
    <span style="font-size: 16px;">TodaysDate</span>

    <table id="PeopleTable" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="720">
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
            <td width="100">
                First Name
            </td>
            <td width="100">
                Last Name
            </td>
            <td width="100">
                Phone Number
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--AddRowsHere-->
    </table>
```

4) Then from a button in code behind you need to get the .htm page as string and replace the text with values you want

```
 Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("PeoplePage.htm"))
        GetHtml = sr.ReadToEnd
 End Using
 GetHtml = Replace(GetHtml, "TodaysDate", Now.ToShortDateString)
```

5) Return this string to the .Net.Mail.MailMessage.Body and send it out as you normally would. Make sure to set MailMesage.IsBodyHtml = True

You could also create the entire string using StringBuilder without using a template.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the content of your email into a server control, you can render it as a string.

```
public static string GetRenderedHtml(this Control control)
{
  StringBuilder sbHtml = new StringBuilder();
  using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sbHtml))
  using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
  {
    control.RenderControl(textWriter);
  }
  return sbHtml.ToString();
}
```

If you have any editable controls (TextBox, DropDownList, etc), you'll need to replace them with Labels. See the following post for a full example and explanation.

http://jrummell.com/send-a-completed-form-email-without-a-stringbuilder

Comment: Thanks. How would i get the control from another page so i could pass it to the function?

Comment: You could use `Control control = new OtherPage().FindControl(controlId);`. Or you could add your control to the current page with `Visible = false`.

Comment: Thanks but will only work with simple html without internal and external css

Comment: Yes, you'll need to either inline your css or add link tags to your control.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an instance of the Page that you want the html from. After that you can use the [Page's Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20b8wk8d.aspx) method (see below example about this being protected) to have it generate the html that would normally be sent to the browser to a HtmlTextWriter.

When you create the HtmlTextWriter, you can use a combination of StringBuilders and TextWriters in order to get the html from the HtmlTextWriter. Something like this.

```
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter SW = new StringWriter(SB);
HtmlTextWriter htmlTW = new HtmlTextWriter(SW);

MyPage page = new MyPage(); // your page here
page.RenderHtml( htmlTW ); //You need to create this method in your page, see below

string html = SB.ToString();
```

So the only problem is that Page.Render is protected. You will need to expose a method in your Page class that is public that calls the Render method.

Something like this should work for that method

```
public void RenderHtml( HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter )
{
    Render( htmlTextWriter );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So Page page = new MyPage();?, Then I put the RenderHtml method in MyPage.aspx? I did that and cannot see it.

Comment: Try MyPage page = new MyPage(). You should see your method then.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It will work for very simple page without internal and external styles.