# exception details via email through httphandler asp.net

Tags: asp.net, exception

i was looking way for catching exception occurred in our website through http handler which will catch exception detail and send the exception detail via mail to admin and as a result admin can see the exception detail and take right step easily. i got a article link from code project which explain how to do it. the link is [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/259139/Send-ASP-NET-formatted-errors-details-via-Email?msg=4034054#xx4034054xx)

but i want some more like when user filling any form and then if any exception occurred then then i want that form screen shot also will be send with mail body. is it possible. so please guide me in such way that i can capture page screen shot with form filled up data from http handler and then i can send it as email to admin. looking for good solution. thanks.

Comment: See [ASP.NET Health Monitoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx). A lot of this is already built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), the best free and open source error reporting tool for ASP.NET.

Comment: It won't give you a screen shot, but will give you user, session, and browser information.

Comment: You can capture the form input html, but its a bit tricky. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660761/get-inner-html-of-aspx-page-in-asp-net-web-project-for-email/7661066#comment9328681_7661066.